# How can I use an adapter to get 120V from my generator to my house?

Tags: wiring, generator

I have a new 3500 portable generator that has an outlet to accept 4-prong for 240 and 3 prong for 120. The house is set up with a four prong male inlet that goes to two electrical boxes. One is isolated by a switch to run all outlets in the house.  My cord is four prong made for generators.

So need to take one end off and convert it to a three prong to plug into the generator.

Comment: So what's your question?  It's never a good idea to modify in any way cords going to electric generators. Include some pictures of the plugs/cords and we might be able to give you  safer solution.

Comment: Do you have an interlock kit? Hooking a generator up to your home with a interlock can kill lineman at the worst and smoke your alternator at the least especially if you start modifying things.

Comment: What make and model is your generator? Can you post photos of your setup please, for that matter?

Comment: @EdBeal Your comment might have a typo? I'm thinking it should say "_without_ an interlock ..."

Comment: Thanks Greg Yes the comment should state without an interlock you can kill a person or damage your equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Now I understand your issue!  Dumb of me, I apologize.  You need 120 and you know those 4-prong plugs are associated with 240V somehow. **You know 240 is not 120**.

***Actually the 4th wire makes it work***.  In North American residential wiring, a 4-prong outlet of these types (NEMA 14) actually contain **both** 120V and 240V. The 4th wire is a "midpoint" between 240V, giving you two separate "legs" of 120V each.  120V household circuits tap one or the other.   The last pin is a safety ground.

Virtually all houses in North America are supplied this way, so this connection allows powering up your whole house.  A 120V generator connection could only power half the circuits.

--

I'm guessing you inherited the *generator interlock or transfer switch* from the last owner.  A 4-prong male is correct; that's called an **inlet**.  Sounds like the last people did stuff right.

All you need is a cable to connect the generator's 4-prong outlet to the house's 4-prong inlet.   Search both of them for a label like  "NEMA 14-20" or "NEMA L14-30", or just  compare the pins to an Internet search for those terms.  From there, we can figure out which cable or adapters you need.

Comment: The generator ground also needs to be evaluated. In the case of a portable generator the ground normally needs to be disconnected from the neutral strap or there will be a parallel ground path creating a path for objectionable current in code verbiage.

Comment: "Objectionable current" - that's the kind that makes your heart go all pitter-patter. Or, alternatively, _stop_ going pitter-patter at all...

Comment: A little of that could be applied to the NEC lawyer who came up with "ground*ed* conductor"...